# How to get WebPartManager for a Page from App?

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2013, csom, sharepoint-apps

I'm trying to get a webPart manager for the page, where my App was added. How can I get the current page server relative Url?

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(SPHostUrl))
{
    var serverRelativeCurrentPageUrl = "/SitePages/MyPage.aspx";
    var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeCurrentPageUrl);
    var wpManager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
    clientContext.Load(wpManager);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no tokens to include the page by default. If you own the layout page, one way is for the iframe to post a message to the parent window and the layout to just post a return message whose value is document.location.

Comment: There is no way to get an owner page URL for an App Part :(

Comment: But I've found that you can get webPartId from query string. This solves my problem.